# How to make a code which generates all integer partitions for number x, which has y as the largest number usable in the partition in C#

Tags: c#, combinatorics

For example, input "5 3" gives 5 as the number of partitions (3+2, 3+1+1, 2+2+1, 2+1+1+1, 1+1+1+1+1), not including 5 or 4+1, since they contain an integer larger than y.

I haven't found any correlation between parameters x and y and the output yet. 
This is the code I have managed to make so far. It detects potential combinations containing 1 and a single other number. I haven't found a way so far to make it detect multiple numbers larger than 1.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] inputs = input.Split();
            int max = Convert.ToInt32(inputs[0]);
            int amount = Convert.ToInt32(inputs[1]);
            int path = max;
            int how_many = 1; // said one is 1+1+1...
            int x = 2;
            while (x <= amount)
            {
                while (path >= x) //only 1 and another number
                {
                    path -= x;
                    how_many += 1;
                }
                path = max;
                x += 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(how_many);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Please add at least some minimum example of what you have tried in code and where you are having difficulties. This is a Q/A site, not a solution building one.

Comment: I haven't really been able to start working on it since I didn't have an idea of what algorithm could work here. However, thank you for the suggestion. I asked a mathematical question regarding this subject here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490828/how-many-ways-can-we-get-a-number-by-addition-if-each-part-of-the-addition-has-t/3490883#3490883, but it didn't help me a lot in finding the solution.

Comment: @Pizza64210 Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, not C# but python3 solution (recursive), applicable in C# just i'm not a windows fan:

```
def solution(n, m):
    if n < 2 or m < 2:
        return 1
    if n < m:
        return solution(n, n)  ## or m = n
    return solution(n-m, m) + solution(n, m-1)

print(solution(5, 3))
#5
print(solution(8,4))
#15
#4+4, 4+3+1, 4+2+2, 4+2+1+1, 4+1+1+1+1
#3+3+2 3+3+1+1 3+2+2+1 3+2+1+1+1 3+1+1+1+1+1
#2+2+2+2  2+2+2+1+1 2+2+1+1+1+1 2+1+1+1+1+1+1 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
```

If it is too slow for big N and M, just use arrays or lists to store
earlier results, it is just "technics".

Comment: Thank you very much! I converted the code to C# and it worked perfectly, though a little slow.